# Nest.js - Sanitize request body

Tags: node.js, express, nestjs

I would like to ask you if nestjs provides some kind of request's body escapeing to prevent XSS attacks.

If it doesn't, is there any "best-practice" to achieve this kind of protection?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can use a interceptor to serialize the data in and out your api.

https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/serialization

And you can use a Sanitize Pipe, just to clean some garbage that comes with your body request based on your parameter type.

```
import {ArgumentMetadata, Injectable, PipeTransform} from '@nestjs/common';
import {plainToClass} from 'class-transformer';

@Injectable()
export class SanitizePipe implements PipeTransform {

    constructor(private readonly className: any) {}

    transform(value: any, metadata: ArgumentMetadata) {
        return plainToClass(this.className, value, {excludeExtraneousValues:true}) as object as any;
    }
}
```

and you can apply this pipe running as a decorator on your controller:

```
@UsePipes(new SanitizePipe(CreateUserDTO))
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: How can this prevent string from malicious content?

Comment: SanitizePipe will prevent you to receive and save information that is not part of what you were expecting on your body or query.

This in some way part of prevention, but I think that you are looking for Helmet in NestJs (https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/security), this is a middleware to protect some XSS, https://helmetjs.github.io/docs/xss-filter/

Comment: ``plainToClass`` is  deprecated . You have to use  ``plainToInstance``

Answer (score 0):

You need to use class-sanitizer and apply sanitize(payload)